# No me valida el XML en la DTD: element is not allowed for content model

Tags: xml

Me dice que el contenido de bank está bien formado pero no validado:

> Error at line 26, column 8: element 'account' is not allowed for content model 'account,customer,depositor)*'

Yo sé que la DTD está interpretada por mí y podría estar mal, pero en el XML la info está bien.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE bank [
<!ELEMENT bank (account,customer,depositor)*>
<!ELEMENT account (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST account account-number ID #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST account branch-name (Downtown|Perryridge|Brighton) #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST account balance NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT customer (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST customer customer-name ID #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST customer customer-street CDATA #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST customer customer-city CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT depositor (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST depositor account-number IDREF #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST depositor customer-name IDREF #REQUIRED>
] >

<bank>
<account account-number="A-101" branch-name="Downtown" balance="500"></account>
<account account-number="A-102" branch-name="Perryridge" balance="400"></account>
<account account-number="A-201" branch-name="Brighton" balance="900"></account>
<customer customer-name="Johnson" customer-street="Alma" customer-city="Palo Alto"></customer>
<customer customer-name="Hayes" customer-street="Main" customer-city="Harrison"></customer>
<depositor account-number="A-101" customer-name="Johnson"></depositor>
<depositor account-number="A-201" customer-name="Johnson"></depositor>
<depositor account-number="A-102" customer-name="Hayes"></depositor>
</bank>
```

Comment: Será que tienes alguna info de "customer" en "account" ? Es decir, faltan algunos elementos de "customer" en la data.

Comment: El título es demasiado amplio y ambiguo. Falta mencionar lo que has buscado/investigado sobre el tema. No está claro quien "te dice" lo referido.

Comment: ya esta corregido.

Comment: Está mejor, pero aún se podría mejorar. Lo básico se indica en [ask].

Comment: ya esta corregido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lo que puede estar mal es el DTD justamente que puede haber más(+) de una instanciación de account, customer y depositor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE bank [
<!ELEMENT bank (account+,customer+,depositor+)>
<!ELEMENT account  EMPTY>
   <!ATTLIST account account-number ID #REQUIRED>
   <!ATTLIST account branch-name (Downtown|Perryridge|Brighton) #REQUIRED>
   <!ATTLIST account balance NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT customer  EMPTY>
   <!ATTLIST customer customer-name ID #REQUIRED>
   <!ATTLIST customer customer-street CDATA #REQUIRED>
   <!ATTLIST customer customer-city NMTOKENS #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT depositor  EMPTY>
   <!ATTLIST depositor account-number IDREF #REQUIRED>
   <!ATTLIST depositor customer-name IDREF #REQUIRED>
   ] >
```

Answer (score 0):

He pasado el documento por varios validadores en línea y **ninguno encuentra el error que refieres**, indicando que el XML es válido.

Para pasar a **otro nivel de prueba** he [convertido el XML a JSON](http://codebeautify.org/xmltojson) y el resultado es un JSON correcto:

```
{
    "bank": {
        "account": [
            {
                "_account-number": "A-101",
                "_branch-name": "Downtown",
                "_balance": "500"
            },
            {
                "_account-number": "A-102",
                "_branch-name": "Perryridge",
                "_balance": "400"
            },
            {
                "_account-number": "A-201",
                "_branch-name": "Brighton",
                "_balance": "900"
            }
        ],
        "customer": [
            {
                "_customer-name": "Johnson",
                "_customer-street": "Alma",
                "_customer-city": "Palo Alto"
            },
            {
                "_customer-name": "Hayes",
                "_customer-street": "Main",
                "_customer-city": "Harrison"
            }
        ],
        "depositor": [
            {
                "_account-number": "A-101",
                "_customer-name": "Johnson"
            },
            {
                "_account-number": "A-201",
                "_customer-name": "Johnson"
            },
            {
                "_account-number": "A-102",
                "_customer-name": "Hayes"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: yo me refería al dtd.

Comment: @TripleX ¿...? He validado el contenido que has compartido. Si preguntas por un contenido erróneo lo lógico es que lo incluyas para que sea revisado.

Comment: yo especifiqué que la info esta bien, la información del esquema xml pero el dtd fue interpretado por mi pero igual no fui muy claro @A. Cedano